# Query an exact date in Visual Studio

Tags: sql, database, date, ms-access

I am writing the following code in `OleDbDataAdapter` of Visual Studio, but the code isn't returning any records.

The fault I found is with this part `{ a.dt = " & dtp4.Value.Date & " }` . I removed it and the query worked fine.

```
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select a.emp_id as Employee_Id, b.emp_name as Employee_Name
from emp_alloc a, emp_info b WHERE a.emp_id = b.emp_id AND a.sft = " & 
cb18.SelectedIndex + 1 & " AND a.dept =  " & txt27.Text & " AND a.dt = " & 
dtp4.Value.Date & "", con)
```

Note:

```
dtp4 -> DateTimePicker
cb18 -> ComboBox
```

Comment: Please help me in adding the condition of matching exact date. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Use parameterized SQL instead of building the SQL via concatenation. It's really as simple as that. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx as an example.

Comment: No the database is in MsAccess

Comment: Parameterized SQL can't be used I think, because I am taking the date value from DataTimePicker. Any other idea??

Answer (score 0):

try like this VB syntax:

```
 { a.dt = '" & dtp4.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "' }
```

Comment: Showing the following error message:
Datatype mismatch in criteria expression

Any other idea??

Comment: Syntax which i provide for VB code. are you using VB Code? for  C# you might change the syntax

Comment: I am running the code in Visual Studio -> Visual Basic platform.